# Insert multiple rows in a table based on ranges between multiple columns in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four columns `YEAR1, MONTH1, YEAR2, MONTH2` of `INT` in a table named `TABEL1`. I want to insert multiple rows into table `TABLE2` for each row in `TABLE1` which have `YEAR` and `MONTH` values between `YEAR` and `MONTH` columns values in `TABLE1`.

Table1 is like:

```
ID   YEAR1   MONTH1   YEAR2   MONTH2   
------------------------------------
1    2010      11     2011      2
2    2012      10     2012      12
```

Table2 should be like:

```
ID   YEAR   MONTH
-----------------
1    2010    11
1    2010    12
1    2011     1
1    2011     2
2    2012    10
2    2012    11
2    2012    12
```

I don't know if I should use while loop or just use select statement. 
I wrote a function for inserting but I found out I cannot use CRUD in user defined function.

```
SELECT Calc(ID,YEAR1,YEAR2,MONTH1,MONTH2) FROM Table1

CREATE FUNCTION Calc(@ID INT, @YEAR1 INT, @YEAR2 INT, @PERIOD1 INT, @PERIOD2 INT)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT
    DECLARE @YEAR INT
    DECLARE @MONTH INT

    SET @YEAR = @YEAR1
    SET @MONTH = @MONTH1
    WHILE (@YEAR <= @YEAR2)
        WHILE (@MONTH <= @MONTH2)
            INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID,YEAR,MONTH)
                        VALUES (@ID,@YEAR,@MONTH)
            SET @MONTH = @MONTH + 1
        END
        SET @YEAR = @YEAR + 1
    END
    RETURN 1
END
```

**UPDATE:**

`MONTH` here is not exactly month. It's actually `SEASON` with the values of `1,2,3,4`. 
Another issue is that `YEAR` and `MONTH` are extracted from Persian dates not Gregorian dates and persian dates are saved as `NVARCHAR` in database.
So, it seems I cannot use `DATE` functions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of good options already mentioned. I would also lean towards a periodics table and a join. One approach might be the following one:

```
USE TEMPDB

CREATE TABLE #Y (YY INT)
INSERT INTO #Y VALUES (2000), (2001), (2002), (2003), (2004),
                  (2005), (2006), (2007), (2008), (2009),
                  (2010), (2011), (2012), (2013), (2014),
                  (2015), (2016), (2017), (2018), (2019)

CREATE Table #M (Mnth INT)
INSERT INTO #M VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), 
                  (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)

SELECT *, CASE WHEN Mnth < 10 THEN CAST (YY AS CHAR (4)) + '0' + CAST (Mnth AS CHAR (2)) 
        ELSE CAST (YY AS CHAR (4)) + CAST (Mnth AS CHAR (2)) END AS Combined   
INTO #Period
FROM #Y
CROSS JOIN #M

SELECT * FROM #Period 

CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ID INT, YEAR1 INT, MONTH1 INT, Combined1 CHAR (6), YEAR2 INT, MONTH2 INT, Combined2 CHAR (6))
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1, 2010, 11, '201011', 2011, 2, '201102'), (2, 2012, 10, '201210', 2012, 12, '201212')

SELECT * FROM TABLE1

SELECT T.ID, P.YY, P.Mnth
FROM #Period AS P
INNER JOIN TABLE1 AS T ON P.Combined BETWEEN Combined1 AND Combined2
ORDER BY 1, 2

--DROP TABLE #M, #Period, #Y, TABLE1
```

Comment: this is my accepted answer since other answers rely on Date functions which is not working in my case

Answer (score 1):

First, create a **[`table-valued function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)** which returns the dates for you according to the `@ID` passed as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDates
(
  @ID INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
  WITH CTE AS
  (
  SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR1, MONTH1, 1) Dates
  FROM T
  WHERE ID = @ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(Month, 1, Dates)
  FROM CTE
  WHERE DATEADD(Month, 1, Dates) < 
    (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR2, MONTH2, 2) FROM T WHERE ID = @ID)
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM CTE
)
```

Then simply use it as (Use `CROSS APPLY` to access the `ID` column)

```
SELECT T.ID,
       YEAR(Dates) [YEAR],
       MONTH(Dates) [MONTH]
FROM T CROSS APPLY dbo.GetDates(ID) TT
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | YEAR | MONTH |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | 2010 |    11 |
|  1 | 2010 |    12 |
|  1 | 2011 |     1 |
|  1 | 2011 |     2 |
|  2 | 2012 |    10 |
|  2 | 2012 |    11 |
|  2 | 2012 |    12 |
+----+------+-------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f6d59c0e7657ee07139c255ed35c73a)**

Comment: You used DATE functions in your answer. What if I want to use seasons instead of months? I mean I have `SEASON` column with the values of `1,2,3,4`

Comment: I think I give you the full function, and you can easy make some changes if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The query becomes trivial if you use [a Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). Calendar tables contain one row per date for eg 100 years in the future with separate fields for year, month, day, day of year, week number and whatever else you may need. Indexing individual fields allows very fast lookups by year, month etc.

Once you have such a table you only need to return the distinct `year` and `month` Calendar values that lie between the `From` and `To` values. If the range values were dates, one could write :

```
select distinct id,Calendar.year,Calendar.Month
from #table1 inner join DimDate as Calendar 
    on Calendar.Date between #table1.StartDate and #table1.EndDate
order by Calendar.Year,Calendar.Month
```

Things become a little more complicated since we need to compare years and months :

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    ID int,
    YEAR1 int,
    MONTH1 int,
    YEAR2 int,
    MONTH2 int   
)
INSERT INTO #Table1
    (ID, YEAR1, MONTH1, YEAR2, MONTH2)
VALUES 
    (1, 2010, 11, 2011, 2),
    (2, 2012, 10, 2012, 12)

select distinct id,Calendar.year,Calendar.Month
from #table1 inner join DimDate as Calendar on 
    (#table1.YEAR1=Calendar.Year and #Table1.Month1<=Calendar.Month 
                                 and (#table1.YEAR2>Calendar.Year or #Table1.Month2>=Calendar.Month)
    ) 
    or  
    (#table1.YEAR1<Calendar.Year and (#table1.YEAR2>Calendar.Year 
                                       or (#table1.YEAR2=Calendar.Year 
                                           and #Table1.Month2>=Calendar.Month)))    
order by Calendar.Year,Calendar.Month
```

The query could be simplified a lot if the source and Calendar tables had a Year-Month column, eg in YYYYMM format. This could be an actual column or a computed and persisted column that's covered by an index :

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    ID int,
    YEAR1 int,
    MONTH1 int,
    YEAR2 int,
    MONTH2 int ,
    YearMonth1 AS YEAR1*100+Month1 persisted,
    YearMonth2 as Year2*100+Month2 persisted
)

create index IX_Table1_YearMonth1 on #Table1 (YearMonth1) Include (Year1,Month1)
create index IX_Table1_YearMonth2 on #Table1 (YearMonth2) include (Year2,Month2)
```

After that, the query becomes a simple :

```
select distinct id,Calendar.year,Calendar.Month
from #table1 inner join DimDate as Calendar on 
    Calendar.YearMonth between #table1.YearMonth1 and #Table1.YearMonth2
order by Calendar.Year,Calendar.Month
```

The execution plan is simple and fast :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query

```
DECLARE @minYear  VARCHAR(10), 
        @minMonth VARCHAR(10), 
        @maxYear  VARCHAR(10), 
        @maxMonth VARCHAR(10) 

SELECT * 
INTO   #table1 
FROM   (SELECT 1    id, 
               2010 year1, 
               11   month1, 
               2011 year2, 
               2    month2 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2    id, 
               2012 year1, 
               10   month1, 
               2012 year2, 
               12   month2) Table1 

SELECT @minYear = Min(year1), 
       @minMonth = Min(month1), 
       @maxYear = Max(year2), 
       @maxMonth = Max(month2) 
FROM   #table1; 

WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @minYear + '-' + @minMonth + '-01') AS dt 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd (month, 1, dt) dt 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  dt < CONVERT(DATE, @maxYear + '-' + @maxMonth + '-01')) 
SELECT id, 
       Year(dt)[year], 
       Month(dt) [month] 
FROM   #table1 Table1 
       INNER JOIN cte 
               ON cte.dt BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT (VARCHAR, year1) + '-' 
                                               + CONVERT(VARCHAR, month1) + 
                                               '-01') AND 
                                 CONVERT( 
                                            DATE, 
                                 CONVERT(VARCHAR, year2) + 
                                 '-' 
                                 + CONVERT(VARCHAR, month2) + 
                                 '-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly use UNPIVOT, here my proposal solution

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE
(
  ID INT,
  YEAR1 INT,
  MONTH1 INT,
  YEAR2 INT,
  MONTH2 INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table1  VALUES (1,2010,11,2011,2),(2,2012,10,2012,12)



SELECT ID, [YEAR],[MONTH]
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, YEAR1,YEAR2,MONTH1,MONTH2
  FROM @Table1
) AS t
UNPIVOT 
(
  [YEAR] FOR YEARS IN (YEAR1, YEAR2)
) AS up
UNPIVOT 
  (
    [MONTH] FOR MONTHS IN (MONTH1,MONTH2)
  ) AS um
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to define one table-valued function and then use this function:

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetMonths] (@year1 int, @month1 int, @year2 int, @month2 int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Months AS
    (
        SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@year1, @month1, 1) AS SomeDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, SomeDate) AS SomeDate
        FROM Months 
        WHERE 
            (DATEPART(year, SomeDate) < @year2) OR
            (DATEPART(month, SomeDate) < @month2)
    )
    SELECT YEAR(SomeDate) AS [YEAR], MONTH(SomeDate) AS [MONTH]
    FROM Months
)
```

INSERT Statement:

```
-- Table 1
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    ID int,
    YEAR1 int,
    MONTH1 int,
    YEAR2 int,
    MONTH2 int   
)
INSERT INTO #Table1
    (ID, YEAR1, MONTH1, YEAR2, MONTH2)
VALUES 
    (1, 2010, 11, 2011, 2),
    (2, 2012, 10, 2012, 12)

-- Table 2
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
    ID int,
    [YEAR] int,
    [MONTH] int
)

-- Insert
INSERT INTO #Table2 (ID, [YEAR], [MONTH])
SELECT t.ID, f.[YEAR], f.[MONTH]
FROM #Table1 t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_GetMonths(t.YEAR1, t.MONTH1, t.YEAR2, t.MONTH2)) f
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Inserted rows:

```
ID  YEAR    MONTH
1   2010    11
1   2010    12
1   2011    1
1   2011    2
2   2012    10
2   2012    11
2   2012    12
```